# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'RLFeedFactoryCommon' not found

Tags: php, opencart-3, opencart-module

**RLProductsRSSGMFeed** - getting an error after installing this extension on the server but the same extension working on the local server

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'RLFeedFactoryCommon' not found in /home/xxx/public_html/oc/project/system/library/RLFeedGMFactory.php:3
```

1. system\library\RLFeedGMFactory.php

   ```
   class RLFeedGMFactory extends RLFeedFactoryCommon
   {
      const FEED_KEY_TOKEN = 'new_products_rss';
      //const FEED_KEY_TOKEN = 'RLProductsRSSGMFeed';

       private $show_price;
       private $show_image;
       private $image_width;
       private $image_height;

    public function BootstrapFeed($controller, $key_hub)
   ```
2. system\library\RLFeedFactoryCommon.php

   ```
    class RLFeedFactoryCommon
    {
       const FILTER_LP = 'latest-products';
       const FILTER_PP = 'popular-products';
       const FILTER_BS = 'best-sellers';
       public $limit;
       public $include_tax;
       public $currency;
       public $logo;
       public $feed_url;
       public $feed_name;
       public $shop_title;
    public $feed_description;
    public $lang;
    /**
     * @var mixed
     */
    public $filter;
   ```
3. admin\controller\extension\feed\new_products_rss.php

   ```
   class ControllerExtensionFeedNewProductsRSS extends Controller 
   {
    public $error = array();
    protected $keyFactory;
    protected $feedFactory;

    public function index(){
        $this->load->library(RLFeedGMFactory::class);
        $this->feedFactory = new RLFeedGMFactory();
        $this->feedFactory->bootstrap_admin_view($this);
    }
   ```

Please help me to fix this issue.
If you need more information I will give you

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue.
actually, the RLFeedGMFactory.php could not find the class from RLFeedFactoryCommon.php so I have simply added a line on the RLFeedGMFactory.php

```
require_once '/home/citytech/public_html/oc/sleeve-modding/system/library/RLFeedFactoryCommon.php';

class RLFeedGMFactory extends RLFeedFactoryCommon
{
const FEED_KEY_TOKEN = 'new_products_rss';
//const FEED_KEY_TOKEN = 'RLProductsRSSGMFeed';

private $show_price;
private $show_image;
private $image_width;
private $image_height;

public function BootstrapFeed($controller, $key_hub)
```

Thank you.